# Configure NGINX to get the remote_user of an already identified user

Tags: nginx

I am building a flask application served by NGINX and Gunicorn, that needs to get access to the user windows account name (to query a database). The user is identified, using windows credentials, while connecting to the portal (through IIS). Since the app is going to be accessible from the company portal, i was hopping to get, from the app, the username without having to check for the user's credentials or by asking with the promp the username. I have read about NGINX remote_user, but this variable is always empty when the request hit NGINX. **Do I have a way to configure NGINX to populate this variable with the name of an already identified user** ? It seems that using basic_auth will force me to keep a file with user's password, which is not possible. 
Here is my NGINX actual conf file:

```
server {

#Docker DNS
resolver 127.0.0.11;

location / {
# Prevent resolution on start
    set $docker_host "app";
    proxy_pass http://$docker_host:8999;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Remote_User $remote_user;
}

   listen 80;

  server_name app.companyDomain.net;
}
```

The NGINX config file : 
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  auto;

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/web.conf; 

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    underscores_in_headers on;
    #gzip  on;

}
```

Here is a the log i get when I try to connect to the app. The $remote_user is empy :

```
10.0.21.1 - - [18/May/2018:14:18:25 +0000] "POST /index HTTP/1.1" 302 269 "http://app.companyDomain/auth/index" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Tablet PC 2.0)" "-"
```